# How to stop spammers registration?

Tags: spam

I have an app that sends emails to customers, and I've noticed a large number of spammers signing up to send spam to users, taking advantage of the tool for sending notifications to customers by email.

Even with the Cloudflare firewall, I noticed that there were registrations made by countries on the continent of Africa and Europe.

These registrations had in common that they used IPs provided by hosting services (eg: AWS, Azure, GCP) and many smaller and unknown providers.
And Cloudflare didn't notice the wrong behavior of these IPs.

After a struggle I managed to create a huge list of ASNs and bar them from registration in the app.

But the spammers came back, so I decided to add two more layers of protection:

- Google reCaptcha to prevent scripts that performed the registration
- Validation with Askimet to see if it's potential spam

After a few months of peace, they returned.

Usually using emails from domains created recently, outside the ".com" standard.

Is there anything else that can be done to stop these malicious users or make their lives more difficult? Because it is impracticable to have to check all user registrations on a daily basis.

Ps.: To validate the registration in the app, the user must click on a link sent to his email and confirm the email.
With that I thought it would reduce the registration, but apparently they managed to automate the validation.

Comment: Since you cannot be sure what the account will do just from the registration, you have to watch what the account is doing after registration. Thus, limit how much mail they can send, watch their behavior, make them actually pay (in terms of money or time, like solving captchas) the more they want to do as long as they did not achieve a reputation for being a good behaving member of your site.

Comment: You're attacking the problem at the wrong end.  Instead of making yourself responsible for picking and choosing who gets to send emails through your system, let the recipients choose using opt-in.  Don't send them anything by default.